# gcc error Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: installation, centos, python, mysql, gcc

I have python-dev (or, as I'm on Centos, python-devel) already installed.

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-libs 
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install MySQL-python
```

How come this command cannot find the `Python.h` header file?

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Before, I upgraded python from 2.6 to 2.7. `find / -name Python.h 2>/dev/null` returns `/usr/include/python2.6/Python.h`, `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, and `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: what is the output of `mysql_config`?

Comment: @ssnobody, `Usage: /usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config [OPTIONS]` and the Options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHA!

It was because I'd installed python2.7 alongside the system python2.6 (following [this great page](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/)). I had to be careful that I referenced *the right python* ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum)) and [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215535/how-to-install-python27-devel-on-centos-6-5) I discovered my problem: `python27-devel` instead of `python-devel` was needed. Ah, ignorance.

Here's the final thing I ran.

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-libs 
sudo yum install python27-devel
sudo yum install MySQL-python 
sudo pip install mysql-python
```